# is it possible to open chrome debugger in separate window? How?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging

I would like to open chrome debugger in a separate window. Is this possible? How?
Internet Explorer opens the debugger in separate window when i press F12 key.

Comment: In my opinion David Hollinshead's answer is now the more accurate/useful as of late '13.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Click on the first icon in the bottom, left-hand corner (two rectangles) - 'undock into separate window'.

Comment: For me, it is at the bottom right, not at the bottom left. And you have to long-press in some cases.

Comment: The trick is to hold down the "Split window" icon for a bit until the menu opens; then you can choose the "Separate window" icon. Tested & working on Chromium 41 for Linux.

Answer (score 111):

You have to press and hold the 'toggle window position' button in the top right corner and then release the mouse on the icon that appears below.

[image: press and hold]

On newer versions of chrome, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Who'd have thought?  Thanks!

Comment: I should avoid comment saying only thanks, but thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the latest solution (tested 21-03-2015). The graphic truly is worth a thousand words.

Comment: they could have made it a dropdown at least. click and hold really not obvious

Comment: Wow. Never would have expected such terrible UX from Google. That option was impossible to find.

Comment: Worst UX design ever. Thanks, though

Comment: Brilliant! Wish I would have searched for this a few days ago. I've been debugging on a 10" monitor. Thank you for the tip. +1 vote =)

Comment: They keep changing this :(

Answer (score 58):

I was driven mad by this recently. It seems you (now?) have to click and hold on this icon. Two widgets appear and, for me at least, the upper widget undocked.

I'm convinced in the past the button in the bottom left used to toggle

Comment: This too was driving me mad.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks! In my opinion this should be the (new, updated) accepted answer.

Comment: There seems to be an extra piece of state or a mode (and a bug). Using the click and hold approach you can choose to dock the dev tools to the bottom or the right hand side of the chrome. Docking to the bottom will single click toggle between a floating window and the bottom. Docking to the right hand side (from being bottom docked) will single click toggle between the right hand side and the bottom. I suspect there is a keyboard shortcut I have only done accidentally that got me into that state initially... (and this is a bug)

Comment: The comment doesn't stand on it's own "hold on this icon" - what icon?