# How to open the Chrome Developer Tools in a new window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I try to use the Chrome Developer Tools, it seems I can no longer view it in a new window.

Is this a bug or was that really an intended change in an update?

How can we open the Chrome Developer Tools in a new window?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo You need to click **and hold** for the option to reveal.

Comment: Hey Side note, on a linux box here and I had to long hold with left mouse button and then click with the mouse wheel to get the undock to happen.

Comment: for real i remember easy button, but now it's ridiculous that i forced to google how to do it.

Comment: Similar to :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936925/is-it-possible-to-open-chrome-debugger-in-separate-window-how

Answer (score 479, accepted):

As of Chrome 52, the UI has changed. When the Developer Tools dialog is open, you select the vertical ellipsis and can then choose the docking position:

[image]

Select the icon on the left to open the Chrome Developer Tools in a new window: [image: multiple windows icon]

---

### Previously

<strike>**Click and hold** the button next to the close button of the Developer Tool in order to reveal the "Undock into separate window" option.</strike>

[image]

Note: A "press" is not enough in that state.

Comment: A "press" is not enough in that state. You need to click **and hold** the button (on the left of the close button) in order to reveal the "Unlock into separate window" option.

Comment: Yes, **`click and hold`** (I am using Chrome for Windows, version 39.x for x64).

Comment: Is there a way to always open in new window? There was an option before but can't find in 39.0.2171.95.

Comment: Are you sure it was an option? If you unlock into a separate window, close the tools, and then subsequently reopen them, they'll be in a separate window (i.e. whatever the last choice was it remembers.)

Comment: What a terrible UI decision; I'm not sure it could be more undiscoverable. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: A "Press" is not enough! 
You can't imagine how much time you just helped me save. Thumb up.

Comment: Good lord... I can't believe I had to look this up, and that click & hold is the answer.

Comment: As of some point mid 2016 you only have to click the vertical ellipses for the docking options to appear, you no longer have to click and hold.

Comment: @ChrisB exactly right. Also, Kyle Hale already already edited the answer though which is nice.

Comment: In Addition, if you want to toggle between your **last two** docking modes you have this keyboard shortcut (that also works for FireFox!) `Ctrl + Shift + D`

Comment: A quicker alternative to undock for those who like keyboard shortcuts: after opening the inspector (e.g. `Ctrl+Shift+I`) you can press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open up the Run Dialog where you can type "undock" and press enter.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

1. click on three dots in the top right ->
2. click on "Undock into separate window" icon

Answer (score 3):

You have to click and hold until the other icon shows up, then slide the mouse down to the icon.

Answer (score 3):

[image: see here]

F12 Call up the toolbar and follow the steps. so easy!

Answer (score 1):

1. Right Click on your Web Page
2. Click on "Inspect"
3. on your Top Right Corner you will see three vertical dots.
4. Choose your best "Dock Side"(Your required will be,'undock into separate window')
   [See the arrow in the Given Screenshot] [Click to view Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOevF.png)

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl+Shift+j` Shows browser developer console in the Console tab

`Ctrl+Shift+c` Shows browser developer console in the Elements tab

Once you have the browser developer console visible, you can detach it pressing `Ctrl+Shift+d`

Answer (score 0):

Just type **ctrl+shift+I** in google chrome & you will land in an isolated developer window.

Comment: this only works if your chrome-developer-tools was already set to open on a new window

Answer (score -1):

If you need to open the DevTools press **ctrl-shift-i**.

If the DevTools window is already opened you can use the **ctrl-shift-d** shortcut; it switches the window into a detached mode.

For example in my case the electron application window (Chrome) is really small.

[image]

It's not possible to use any other suggestions except the **ctrl-shift-d** shortcut

Comment: I just tried this answer and it seems to work well on Windows. I also tried it on Mac, but the shortcuts are different. Open the DevTools (**cmd+option+i**) and switching to other dock side (**cmd+shift+d**). Also on Mac, directly using cmd+shift+d w/o opening first the DevTools would yield to a different functionality.