# How to open the Chrome Developer Tools in a same window?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How to open the Chrome Developer Tools in a same window? Basically it should have opened on the same window but in my chrome it opened in a new window, need it on same window to view side by side. how can i open the inspect(devtools) on same window?

i tried to watch seting but i sees nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open the Chrome Developer Tools in a new window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668827/how-to-open-the-chrome-developer-tools-in-a-new-window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

click on this icon to switch to side